# Why does 了 change in 突然父亲嘘(了)一口气?

Tags: translation, meaning, particles

The sentence is

> (1) 突然父亲嘘了一口气

and

> (2) 突然父亲嘘一口气

I would have understand them if it's not the for the "突然" part.

My take:

- (1) *"Suddenly father exhaled (once)"* (like "ooooh" and then maybe
  died).
- (2) *"Suddenly father started to perform an exhale."* (and after he
  performed it maybe he died).

P.S. Sentence (2) As far as I see doesn't have niether of those readings:

1. Conteractual. "If something happens/ed, then he has/would exhaled.
2. Suprise. He can exhale?!
3. Probable. Well, he can exhale.
4. Future. He might exhale.
5. Deductive. He exhale. (I can say that based on some reasoning)
6. Abilitive. He can exhale.

that 突然 eliminate all those readings and I'm lost a bit.

Comment: see dictionaries, why not "exhale" （with verbal measure:一口气) instead of "give/perform a breath";小马词典： 嘘 exhale; hiss, regarding (1) also see jukuu：嘘一口气 2 examples: 1.便嘘了一口气 released his breath, 4.宽慰地嘘了一口气 gave a sigh of relief,

Comment: The problems is of coures is not in verb meaning, but in having 了 and not having 了 with 突然 and 一口气. I'll fix the verb translation. Thanks.

Comment: looking for examples of 突然 not followed by 了？
突然訇的一声, 震得山鸣谷应，突然默不作声，突然发生吵架，严寒突然来临，突然改变方向，他突然一跳, 用拳头在桌子上一砸（all in bkrs）

Comment: So it is a narrative? Looks plausible, but Is that a description of a real situation or of an imaginary one? Who started that narrative and why? (You might think it's unimportant but for me this info is vital).

Comment: May it be a painter who explains what he sees in his mind? I don't think it might be a news reporter. Right? Can it be a historian, explaining some past chain of events?

Comment: it would seem that in the presence of other indicators
of completed action (like adverb 突然 and verbal measure 一口气，cf。above 突然改变方向, 他突然一跳）了 is not obligatory）

Comment: I think 了 obligatory when we speak about real thing. If we speak about possible, imaginary and habitual things 了 can't be used. Thats the reason for me to ask you about context of your long example. In you expample you demonstrated that 突然 can be used in an imaginary context thus rendering 了 out.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer for ref:
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/18061/13501

If you look at my previous answer, I explained:

For the first and second, both mentioned that 了 is used to denote the completion of an action.

For the fourth one, I mentioned that 了 is used only to soften the tone.

In the example above,

(1)突然父亲嘘了一口气

(2)突然父亲嘘一口气

The first sentence is denoting the completion of the action "exhale", because indeed you are talking about things in the past and father has done and ended exhaling.

However, most Chinese native speakers use it, not to express this meaning, but the fourth meaning actually, which is, only to soften the tone.

Despite the fact mentioned, please note that you cannot use 了 after any verb if the **ACTION** is NOT completed.

*One more point to notice:*
The first and second meaning of 了 are only applicable to action verbs. For position verbs(有，坐，死...), they should follow the adjective rule, which is, when confronting these verbs, th meaning should be "become (verb status)".
Example: 我有了。 or  他死了。

Comment: 在墙上挂了一幅画? Does it mean that "a picture" does not hang now? Where is completion?

Comment: The action is indeed completed, because currently, no one is hanging the picture, instead the picture was already hung by someone, and that person is no longer hanging the picture now! It is the action which is completed, it does not mean that the picture(object) cannot keep its status of being hung.

Comment: I thought this statement was about "There is something on a wall" and not about "Someone hanged a picture on a wall". Can my and your readings be correct simultaneously?

Comment: I don't quite get you. Did you mean if 在墙上挂了一幅画? can be translated to "There is something on a wall"? I think another translation will be "There is something being hung on a wall", which should require someone to do it.

Comment: Yes. Can it? Are you sure my translation "that a thing just hangs there" is 100% inaccurate? Thanks for your help by the way :)

Comment: If you want to say "There is (something) on a wall", it should be 有（一些东西）在墙上。 To illustrate, "There is a picture on a wall", should be 有一幅画在墙上。

Comment: How can we say that " A picture hangs on the wall"? Without -zhe, without -you, without implicit "being" who did the hanging. Is it possible?

Comment: 他死了一年. Does this sentence too implies that someone killed 他 or is 他 just being dead for a year?

Comment: Come on, I don't know if you super bla bla boy are a native speaker, but what coobit wrote or constructed can def be understood as "there is/hangs a picture on the wall". In this case I'd say it's interchangeable with 着。

Comment: @coobit Yes, this sentence tells us that the man died is just being dead for one year

Comment: @coobit No, it does not mean that someone killed him. See my edits in order to understand more.

Comment: @andrew My mother language is Chinese, my mother tone is not Mandarin. The translation, though acceptable, will deter you from understanding the existence of 了

Answer (score 0):

突然 … V [expressing **change of state**] => 了 + object.

Comment: So? How do you translate those sentences? In what context each could have been used?

Comment: Only the first can be used. You have to use 了 in state changes.