# Which verbs DO NOT go with 了 and or 过?

Tags: grammar, mandarin

I remember reading that some verbs don't accept 了 or 过.

Side question： When I use a word like 昨天 or 以前 do I use 了 or is it redundant? e.g. 昨天我去买了一台电脑 or 昨天我买一台电脑

Comment: I don't know any verb that doesn't accept 了 or 过.  "昨天我去买了一台电脑"  is correct

Comment: cf.＂实用现代汉语语法＂关于动词成句的问题｜五、下列动词后一般不能用动态助词＂了＂、＂着＂、＂过＂或补语（但句末可以用动态（就是语气？）助词＂了＂）：１。关系动词＂是＂、＂作为＂等；２。表示使动意义的＂使＂、＂叫＂、＂让＂等；３。能愿动词；４。＂觉得＂、＂显得＂、＂以为＂等动词不能用动态助词和补语；＂知道＂、＂认识＂、＂明白＂、＂承认＂和＂有＂不能补语，通常也不用动态助词，但表示＂由不知道到知道＂、＂由无到有＂这一改变时，可以用＂了＂。例如：（１）他又有了一个新的女朋友。比较：他有女朋友，我没有女朋友。（２）昨天在晚会上他认识了很多人。比较：这个人我认识。（３）他刚才承认了这件事是他干的。（意思是＂以前他不承认＂）比较：他承认这件事是他干的。

Comment: See my answer: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/18061/13501

Comment: If you use 昨天 without 了, it sounds like: When I was going to buy a computer yesterday, (something happened).

Answer (score 5):

过 and 了 are **aspect** markers, and can be used with any verbs, including 过 and 了 themselves.

过 is the **experential aspect**, indicating that an event has taken place (or the negation thereof), regardless of timeframe *(there is no tense in Chinese)*. 我去过巴黎二十次。 (I have had the experience of visiting Paris twenty times.) 我没去过越南。 (I have not had the experience of going to Vietnam.) 我从来没看过电影。 (I have never had the experience of seeing a movie.)

了 is the **perfectative aspect**, indicating that an event has been completed, again regardless of time. 我买了个新脚踏车。 (I have bought a new bike.) 吃了饭以后可以逛逛街。 (We can go for a walk after we have finished eating [future]).

Both aspects can be expressed simultaneously: 我吃过了。 They can also be used with other complemented verbs: 我看得见过了。

Aspects can be used with any verb. The only restriction is context and combining conflicting aspects. For example, using durative 着 with completion aspects 过 and 了 makes no sense.

As for your side question: since there is no tense in Chinese, it does not matter in which time frame these aspects are used. The use of 昨天 or 以前 indicates the time, whereas 过 and 了 indicate completion, regardless of time.

Comment: re:"在了"
Does NP+在了+NP exist?  As is easy to check V/A+在了NP occurs frequently,e.g. jukuu: 这种推断是错误的，错在了多个方面,都花在了更换刹车方面,伞兵部队空投在了西奈半岛,汽车停在了汽车站,这堆书倒在了地板上,他的小腿
绊在了床柱上.（It also seems   了 could not 
be replaced by the other aspect particles 过.着)
It seems 
 ＊他在了家，＊在了位（＊=ungrammatical) cf. 他回了家 ,V+在＋NP，cannot generally  be transformed to V+在了＋NP，e。g。in 呆在家里，留在家里，他住在他家。Thus it seems that V/A+在了NP only exists for some V/A even though V/A+在+NP may exist.  V/A must act in the direction into or onto NP (even in the case of 错在了多个方面?)

Answer (score 2):

I think the distinction is a soft one, rather than compulsory.
When you stress you have done something and there is some action or change in the process, use `過`.
When you stress you have completed doing something, use `了`; it is somewhat like perfection, but see below.

For brevity, call

```
(a)昨天我去买一台电脑
(b)昨天我去买了一台电脑
(c)昨天我去买過一台电脑
```

(a) is okay but rare, sounds a bit dry. It reminds me of a very formal narrative without sentiment (in a fiction), or a formal speech.

(b), however, is very common. It occurs to me German usage of auxiliary `haben` "have" (or `sein` for a group of verbs such as `gehen` and `kommen`) is also soft: it does not strongly stress perfection, but loosely equivalent to English past tense.

(c) is okay but somewhat dubious, probably because `買` occurs within a short moment, and little is "taking place".
But consider the context: You and your friends are talking about a computer sales in that store who is very bad-tempered, and you say, `昨天我去買過一台電腦，店員真的好兇啊!` you are stressing you really have seen him, and he is really bad-tempered. This is perfect. You have tried something, and found something new.

I can think of a good example: as of `愛` (following Enrico's example), one usually says `我愛他`, but it is odd to say `我愛過他`. Why? because it changes little visible to "love" someone.
But does it have its own appropriate context? yes! Consider: A and B are talking about C. Now A reveals to B that A and C once had a relationship, but broke up.
Still somewhat remorseful, A remarks: `我愛過他` It is appropriate then. (as a side remark, `愛` is so formal-sounding and really uncommon in spoken Mandarin, no matter parental love or romantic love....at least in Taiwan I think.)

Answer (score 1):

Many of my students have this question. And what you are trying to ask is not which verbs don't use 了, but **which verbs don't use 了 to express past tense**.

Basicaly Mandarin "separates" verbs into action verbs and stative verbs. So, any verb that is not an action, for example, 有 是 在 etc don't express past tense using 了.

Here's a small list. Since I'm not a native speaker, I'm not sure what is an action or not in Chinese. Hopefully someone can help us make a more detailed one:
是
有
在
"mental" verbs: 知道、喜欢、爱、etc.
modal verbs: 应该、要、会、能、可以、etc.
adjectives

If the above verbs take 了, it indicates a change of state. For example:
我是大学生了。 I'm a graduate student **now**.

Comment: assuming Q only concerns ＂了＂as 动态助词 not 语气助词，cf。＂实用现代汉语语法＂动态‌​助词｜一、动态助词＂了＂２。状态动词与动态‌​助＂了＂｜状态动词不表示动作，而表示一种状‌​态。这种状态有起点、可以持续，没有终点，或‌​语言表达不关心其终点。如＂饿＂、＂生气＂、‌​＂累＂、＂困＂、＂病＂、＂醉＂等。状态动词‌​用上＂了＂，表示状态出现。例如：（１）为了‌​帮你打毕业论文，他已经累  **了**  三天了。这个句子的意思是＂累＂的状态已经‌​出现，而且还在持续。（２）老师病 **了**  三天了。这个句子与上面的句子一样，表示＂‌​病＂的状态已经出现，持续了＂三天＂，而且还‌​在持续。某些形容词，如＂高兴＂、＂贵＂、＂‌​红＂、＂亮＂也有类似的用法。例如：（３）在‌​会上，他的脸红  **了**  一阵子，又白了，白 **了**  一阵子，又红起来，真是如坐针毯。这个句子‌​中＂红了一阵＂、＂白了一阵＂中的＂了＂都表‌​示状态结束。

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes more sense to say that the verbal suffix 了 is not used with certain actions/events rather than with certain verbs. Typically, 了 is not used in the following cases when the actions/events are non-intentional (in these cases, 到 is used):

1. 他昨天看到姚明。(He happened to see Yao Ming yesterday.)
2. 我今天早上收到一个从中国来的包裹。(I happened to receive a parcel from China this morning.)
3. 我最近听到一些坏消息。(I happened to hear some bad news lately.)
4. 你们有没有捡到一个黑色的钱包？(Did you happen to find a black wallet?)

If we use the same verbs with 了, the actions/events are interpreted as intentional:

- 1a. 你的报告我看了两遍，写得不错。(I have read (seen) your report twice. Well done.)
- 2a. 这家咖啡店真贵，一杯咖啡收了我十五块钱。(This coffee house is really expensive. They
  charged me (collected from me) 15 dollars for a cup of coffee.)
- 3a. 我听了他们的意见，但还是失败了。(I took (listen to) their advice, but in the end
  I still failed.)
- 4a. 我捡了整天垃圾，累死了。(I have been picking up trash the whole day long. I
  am exhausted.)

Answer (score -1):

昨天我去买了一台电脑 is correct.
When you use chinese sentenses which have a meaning similar to English sentence of present perfect or past perfect, 过 or 了 should always be used.

eg. 我通过了这次考试。I have passed the exam.