# Can one use 过 in conjunction with 知道?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-requests

I am investigating the use of 知道 in the past tense. As "知道了“ does not clearly mean "knew" but could be more closely translated as "now I know!", a change of state from not knowing to knowing.
How would one translate "I knew"? (As in, I did know before, but now no longer do)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: see previous Q:  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/20856/which-verbs-do-not-go-with-%e4%ba%86-and-or-%e8%bf%87  esp. ＂知道＂不能用动态助词 （了、着，过）
suggestion：enter "I once knew" into jukuu, get 9 relevant samples (1-9), esp. 6.我曾经认识

Comment: @user6065 : it is a flawed answer.

Comment: Q  quoted in comment #1 says: 但表示＂由不知道到知道‌​＂、＂由无到有＂这一改变时，可以用＂了＂,
知道了 can be used for "changing from not knowing to knowing", 我曾经认识 "I once knew" irrelevant, how about
  "no longer know" 不再知道／现在不知道

Comment: Some people used it on the Web. However, those sentences are probably not the case you are talking about because they do not mean "unknown" again.

[你听过*知道过*哪些咎由自取的故事。？](https://www.zhihu.com/question/60375126) ... 

[我们*知道过了*这位艺术家。](http://www.duolingo.cn/comment/6960835) ... 

[我从未*知道过*有什么苦恼是不能为一小时的读书所排遣的。](http://zaojv.com/s2724887.html) ... 

[那*知道过*的，必得一次又一次地重新知道；懂得过的，还要再来一次，才能真的接近懂。](http://www.jianshu.com/p/78598cdb5099) ... 

[一個曾經愛過，而且*知道過*關係的人，他​​是可以單獨的](http://blog.xuite.net/tonycjones/twblog/171988447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do take note that some sentence meaning otherwise under special context.

"知道了"  is a good example.

Even 知道 carry out the meaning of "know", but "知道了"  in some conversions mean "okay"(noded).

For example：

```
Q：“如果经过超市，顺带买瓶酱油”  If you happens to pass the store, buy me a bottle of soyasauce.

A：“知道了！” Okay （or you can reply "好的!"）
```

In different dialect such as Cantonese, sometimes it uses as "understood" rather than 清楚了， 了解了, 明白了

```
我知道了, 你是说如果把醋倒进去它就会溶掉。 Now I understood, you mean if you pour in vinegar, it will melt.
```

Because 过 in Mandarin carry the meaning "over/pass"(instead of before) in certain conditions, so you can't use it. As mentioned by @Alex, you can't "un-learn", "de-notify" something.

In case of "know", to say "I already know that", you can't say, "知道过” ， but "我【已经】知道了”， “我【早】知道了”。

However, you can say "I learn it before but I forget".

这把戏， 我从前【学过】， 不过我忘了。

Comment: You can add in your answer that one cannot use 过 in conjunction with 知道 - technically once you know something, you cannot ' unknown' it

Comment: But you can "forget" something you learn ;-)

Comment: hah that's true you can forget it but it's different from unknowing it.  The info is in your brain, you just failed to retrieves it.  Unless brainwash is a thing in the future

Comment: How would "我之前知道" be understood? Is it incorrect?

Comment: @Somniare  "之前知道" use to describe associated events.  Please post a new question and ask the different of "之前" versus  ”过“.

Comment: @mootmoot [said question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/24122/what-would-the-meaning-of-%e4%b9%8b%e5%89%8d%e7%9f%a5%e9%81%93-be-and-%e4%b9%8b%e5%89%8d%e7%9f%a5%e9%81%93%e4%ba%86)