# Confusing 了1 and 了2

Tags: grammar, particles, tense

One of the functions of 了 is marking the completion of an action. (了1) Another function is marking a change of state. (了2) Personally it is sometimes difficult for me to distinguish between these two functions.

Here are two examples, where 了 is used. But I can't figure it out which function it has. (completion of an action 了1, or change of state 了2)

我得把书换了。

1: I must return the book and complete this action.

2: (I didn't have to return the book before but) Now I have to return the book.

我们上楼去，先把借书证办了。

And if 了 acts as the completion marker, can it be used with present and future tenses?

The two examples provided above, seem to in present and future tense.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are from *New Practical Chinese Reader 2*.  In the first case, the original snippet is:

> 现在我们就去借书，我们从这儿出去。**我得先把上次借的书还了**。
>
> [image: image from textbook]

(Note it's 还 = "return", not 换 = "exchange".)

You can see from the image that he hasn't yet returned the book, so it's definitely not a completion 了.  It looks like a change of state 了: originally he said 我们就去借书 = "we're are going to borrow books", but realized he has to return his book first.

(On the other hand, it could just be a 语气词 (modal particle), because 把上次借的书还 without the 了 sounds unnatural or even wrong.)

> 办公室在三楼，**我们上楼去，先把借书证办了**。
>
> [image: image from textbook]

Again, we can see from the image in the textbook that they haven't gone upstairs yet, so it cannot be a completion 了.  I think it's a change of state 了; basically they were doing something (checking out the Beijing library), and now he's saying they need to do something else (go upstairs and get a library card).

---

I suggest avoiding relating 了 and "tense" (the keyword here is "aspect", not "tense").

> 我走了！
> I'm leaving.  [present tense]
>
> 等我回家了再说。
> Wait until I get home, and then we can speak. [future tense]
>
> 昨天我没去公园。
> I didn't go to the park yesterday. [past tense without 了]

In regards to...

> And if 了 acts as the completion marker, can it be used with present and future tenses?

I think it would be fairly rare, if not impossible, to have something considered "completed" when we're talking about the present or future.  It sounds like it'd just be a grammar error (outside of science fiction with time travel).

Also completion 了 is [not used with all verbs](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/20856/8099).  My teacher told me a good example of her student getting it wrong once: if I remember correctly her grandfather had passed away, and her student asked her:

> <s>他喜欢了做什么？</s>
> What did he like to do?

The other thing that students don't realize (at least, it took me a long time to realize) is that, a lot of the time 了 is not used:

> 昨天，我看见一只鹿。
> Yesterday, I saw a deer.
>
> 昨天，我在学校学得很努力。
> Yesterday, I studied hard.

This is unlike e.g. past tense, where it's far less optional.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to view 了1 and 了2from another angle:

**(了2)** indicates "change of state", which simply means "**something wasn't before, now is**".

- 下雨 **了**。(It wasn't raining, but now it is.)
- 宝宝 会 说话 **了**。(He couldn't before)
- 他 当 经理 **了**。(He wasn't a manager before.)
- 我 饿 **了**。(Now I am hungry.)
- 妈妈 老 **了**。(now mother is getting old.)

**(了1)** is called **aspect**, which is not the same as tense. Tense is about when an action happens: past, present, or future. With regards to 了 (le); **aspect** is about whether the action is complete in a certain time frame, regardless of tense.

"我得把书還[huán]**了1**" is an action to be complete in the future, "但是書外皮已經破**了2** (it wasn't broken before), also note that 破 is not a verb representing action.

Hope this helps.

https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_completion_with_%22le%22

https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Change_of_state_with_%22le%22

Answer (score 0):

现在我们就去借书，我们从这儿出去。我得先把上次借的书还了。

My understanding of this sentence is that to borrow books (去借书) is the main purpose to come to the library. (先把上次借的书还了) is a secondary task but it has to be done before 去借书. （maybe there is a limitation on the number of books that we can borrow). Therefore the final word 了 can be seen as a "modal particle", or just a convention to end this sentence.

You can also say 我先去还上次借的书.

Formally, this sentence can be reconstructed as 我先去还书, 再去借书.