# position and meaning of 了 in "一...就" construction

Tags: grammar

I'm a little bit confused how to translate these sentences:
1)今天我一下课就去看他 (is it "As soon as the class is over I'll come to see him"?)
我一下课就去看他了 ( "as soon as the class was over I came to see him?")
2)他一到中国就给我来了个电话("as soon as he came to China he gave me a phone call"?)
3)姐姐一毕业就参加工作了( "as soon as she graduated she started working"?)
姐姐一毕业就参加工作("as soon as she graduates she will start working"?)

can i say "我一吃了饭就出去了?

Comment: why not test proposed sentence by feeding e.g. ＂一吃了＂to jukuu,there seems to be only one relevant example:1.  "Take this powder," Aladdin said to the Princess. "Put it in the Magician's food. When he eats it, he will fall into a deep sleep."
 “拿好这药粉，”阿拉丁对公主说，“把它放进魔术师的食物里。他一吃了这药粉，就会蒙头大睡的。” indicating "我一吃了饭就出去(了)" may refer to future.

Comment: the following info of course contained in dictionaries and grammars, e.g. "汉语８００虚词用法词典＂：  **一（副）、和＂就、便＂组成＂一。。。就／便。。。＂格式。**  **１。表示一种动作或情况出现后紧接着发生另一种动作或情况.**  （１）一＋动词／动词词组 A。＂。。。＂与＂就。。。＂的主语相同（１）中午一下课，学生们就向食堂走去。（２）你放心吧，我一到就给你电话。（３）我的包就放在桌子上，你一看就看见了。（４）一听见闹钟响，我就赶紧起床。（５）路上都是雪，特滑，我一出门就摔了一跤。（６）昨天晚上我一洗完澡就上床睡了。（７）我一出机场就看见来接我的爸爸妈妈了。（８）一响雷就＂哗哗＂地下起雨来了。B。＂。。。＂与＂就。。。＂的主语不同（１）他一说大家就都笑了。（２）门铃一响，我就去开门。（３）这孩子聪明，老师一讲他就懂了。（４）我们一摇，树上的枣就掉下来了。（５）他跳起来一投，球就进了。（６）我一咳嗽，妈妈就让我多穿衣服。（７）我一到她就说：＂你又迟到了。＂（８）我一说要推荐信，老师就答应给我写一件。 **（２）一＋形容词／形容词词组** （１）她脸一红，扭头就跑出去了。（２）天一冷，学校就放暖气了，冻不着我们的，妈妈你就放心吧。（３）我刚站起来，眼睛一黑就摔倒了。（４）天一暖和，地上的雪就都化了.

Comment: （５）这孩子，衣服稍微一旧就不穿了，仍了可惜，我就穿了。（６）我一忙就把这件事给忘了，实在对不起。（７）我见了他一紧张就不知道说什么好了。  
   **２。表示只要发生某一个情况，就会出现或发生另一种情况.**  （１）我一喝咖啡或茶就睡不着觉，所以我只能喝白水。（２）他一喝醉就大喊大叫，有时还唱歌。（３）昨晚一点多才睡，今天我一坐下来听课就打磕睡。（４）一听到雷声就害怕。（５）一回到家里就感到舒适轻松了很多。（６）一想起这件事我就头疼。（７）人胖就容易得高血压，所以我得减肥。   **３。表示某一动作发生后延续的时间长。**  一＋动词＋时量词组（１）他在电话脑前一坐就是几个小时。（２）我在中国一住就是十年，这里已经成了我的第二故乡。（３）你这次出国留学，一去就是两年，要不想家才怪呢。（４）我这把小提琴买回来后，从没拉过，一放是十几年，琴弦却断了。（５）这项工作我一干就干八年，现在要我放下，还真有点儿不习惯。（６）她口才真好，一讲就是两个钟头，妙语连珠，风趣幽默。大家不时报以热烈的掌声。     **二、表示先做某个动作，下文说明动作结果或结论。**  一＋动词／动词词组（１）我一看，朋友们都来了，心里有说不出的高兴。（２）我一想，觉得你说得也对。（３）我一尝，又酸又甜，还真好吃。（４）我一打听，他们说王老师早搬家了。（５）大夫一检查，果然是重感冒。

Comment: （６）卷子发下来一看，真是一百分。（７）一出门，感觉外边比屋里冷多了。赶紧又回去穿了件毛衣。（８）我一躺下，得先看一会儿书才能睡着。（９）一听说哥哥考上了大学，全家人高兴极了。

Comment: OP did not ask about the meaning of 一＋VP，就。。。，but only about （１st）了。Regarding this it seems indeed that 一＋V+了，就。。。is relatively uncommon, thus none of the examples from "汉语８００虚词用法词典＂ quoted above have such 了, feeding 一吃了 to jukuu
only yields one example (s.a.), whereas the 1st 4 examples for 一吃 also all have 一吃...就 but no 了，and 2 of these have 吃完。Also note what "实用现代汉语语法" says comparing use of aspect particle 了 to that of complement of result (e.g. 完）：＂在有些动词后面加上动态助词＂了＂表示动作对受事者产生某种结果（如＂破坏＂、＂消失＂等），与某些结果补语或趋向补语表示的意义相同， **只是在所表示的结果方面，更笼统些**   。例如：（１）小妹刚才不小心打了一个杯子。（打破）（２）他买这本书花了两块钱。（花掉）

Comment: 这类动词有：吃、忘、丢、失、拉（阐）、喝、咽、吞、酒、泼、扔、放、涂、擦、抹、碰，摔、磕、撞、伤、打、杀、宰、切、煮、冲、卖、还、毁、烧、花，撕、扯、倒、炸等。

Answer (score 2):

[一(X)就(Y)] is a very common sentence structure

(X) is the condition or requirement.  When this condition or requirement is met, then the following action or event (Y) would occur.

Depend on the context [一(X)就(Y)] functions as following:

1. [**once** (X) **then / immediately** (Y) ]

Example: [**一**(吃完飯)**就**(出去)] = [**once** I (finish dinner), **then** I would (go out )**immediately**]

吃完飯 is the condition / requirement that being met; 出去 is the following action that only occurs after the condition is met.

2. [**Whenever** (X) **then / immediately** (Y) ]

Example: [**一**(上課)**就**(睡覺)]= [ **whenever** I ( go to classes), I would **immediately** (fall to sleep)]

上課 is the condition/ requirement that being met; 睡覺 is the resulting action/event that always occur when the condition/ requirement is met.

> can i say "我一吃了饭就出去了?"

If by saying "一吃了", you meant 'once I finish eating', you can say "我一吃了饭就出去了". But it is better to say "我一吃**完**饭就出去了" (once I **finish** dinner, I would go out). Because "一**吃了**" in "我一**吃了**饭" can also be interpreted as "whenever I **eaten** dinner".

You didn't mean to say "I go out whenever I eaten dinner" I suppose?

As for your example sentences:

1. 今天我一下课就去看他 - (下课=X; 去看他=Y ) "Once I finished classes for today, I went to see him immediately."
2. 他一到中国就给我来了个电话- (到中国=X; 给我来了个电话=Y)" Once he arrived in China, he immediately gave me a phone call."
3. 姐姐一毕业就参加工作了- (毕业=X; 参加工作=Y) " Once my sister graduated, she joined the work force immediately.)

Comment: Is the "一" always obligatory? Found this sentence on my book:
昨天我们把他送到车站就回家了.

Comment: @dont-care The question asked  “一…就” structure, if you take away  "一" and write "今天我下课就去看他" the sentence would still make sense. The small difference is it doesn't emphasis  the sense of urgency or immediacy without "一".

Answer (score 0):

I won't bother to explain what means by 一...就... as the other answers explained well that it means "as long as... , ..."

I want to explain the meaning of 了 in a different aspect.

One of my previous answers explained [the use of 了](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/18061/13501).

I think 了 in the sentence structure is only used to soften the tone, without any actual meaning conveyed. (i.e. the 4<sup>th</sup> meaning)

Answer (score -1):

All correct.

You can say 我一吃了饭就出去了(I went out as soon as I finished my food.).
If want to express "I'll go out after finishing this meal". i would say "我一吃完饭就出去".