# Proper use of 了 in Chinese

Tags: past-tense

For my Chinese language class, I need to go through this practice worksheet and fill out which uses of 了 are correct. However, while I think I know decently when to use 了， I am not sure about some of my answers, as we have not discussed some things in class.

| 我们现在一起吃饭了。       | I'm not sure about this one. I think it might be correct because it could say "Now we can eat," which uses 了 to indicate a change.
            |
| 我明天要跟你去健身房了。   | I don't think this one is correct because it uses 明天 and 要which  indicates it will happen in the future.                                          |

| 我已经吃了午饭。           | I think this one is correct, it says "I already ate lunch."                                                                                          |

| 我看电影了。               | This one seems correct, "I watched TV."                                                                                                              |

| 她穿新的裙子了             | This one also seems to use 了correctly, it says "She wore a new skirt."                                                                              |
| 我去了中文课了。           | Again, this one also seems to use 了 correctly, I believe it translates to "I have been going to Chinese class."                                     |
| 他会说中文了。             | This one also seems correct. "He can now speak Chinese."                                                                                             |

| 你真的买了两个新的电视吗？ | I also think this is correct, because the 了 occurs before the numbers and  indicates a the past tense of 买。 “Did you really buy two televisions?" |

| 他买四本书了               | This one isn't correct because 了occurs after the quantity and not before the quantity and after the verb like it should.                            |

| 你们回家了                 | I think this one is correct, it translates to "You have returned home."                                                                              |

Comment: "电影" is usually "movie".

Comment: 看了电影， 看电影了both exist see jukuu,  我明天要跟你去健身房了??  regarding 了 for future action see recent https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23175/why-cant-%e4%ba%86-be-used-to-indicate-a-completed-action-that-has-yet-to-come/23191#23191

Comment: See here. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/23192/9732

Answer (score 1):

I got this from another forum, I find it useful:

> 了和过的区别
>
> 了和过都能用在动词后面。   了 有表示过去时，现在进行时，将来时的意思。   如：我去了一趟超市。（过去）   我睡觉了。（现在）
>   我到了给你打电话。（将来）
>   过 只表示过去发生的某些事情。不能表示现在时和将来时。
>    如：我去过中国。
>
> 了 和 过的用法是非常相似的，希望你能慢慢体会，多多练习。(ง •_•)ง,加油

My take on your sentences:

1. 我们现在一起吃饭。
2. 我明天要跟你去健身房了。
3. 我已经吃了午饭。
4. 我看电影了。
5. 她穿了新的裙子。
6. 我去了中文课了。（第二个‘了’是语气助词）
7. 他会说中文了。
8. 你真的买了两个新的电视吗？
9. 他买了四本书。
10. 你们回家吧。

Answer (score 1):

我明天要跟你去健身房了 and 我明天要跟你去健身房 are not the same mean.

我明天要跟你去健身房了。 means in the past, I didn't need to go to gym, while I have to do it tomorrow.

我明天要跟你去健身房。 it has nothing related to the past, just means that I will do that tomorrow.